# PHP calculator using $_POST superglobal

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to PHP and for the past few days I've been taking on challenges to improve on my php. I decide to build a BMI calculator in php that will be calculated based on the user's input of his weight and height. To begin with, BMI is expressed as weight(in kg)/height(meters squared); This means however that if a user inputs the weight in pounds and height in centimeters, they should be converted before calculation is done so this is what I've done for the past 3 days based on this understanding:

my php code:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['calculate'])){
        //once form has been submitted
        $weight = $_POST['weight'];
        $height= $_POST['height'];
        $kilo= isset($_POST['kg'])? $_POST['kilo']:null;
        $pounds= isset($_POST['pounds'])? $_POST['pounds']:null;
        $cm= isset($_POST['cm'])? $_POST['cm']:null;
        $meters= isset($_POST['meters'])? $_POST['meters']:null;

        $meter2 = pow($meters, 2);
        $bmi= $kilo / $meter2;
        //check the units first
        if ($kilo=='kg' && $height=='meters'){
            //calculate BMI using kg/m2     

            return $bmi;
            }

            echo $bmi;


        $message="success!";


    }

    else {
        $message="Please input data";
        }   
    ?>
```

My HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My BMI</title>
</head>


<body>

<h1>My BMI</h1>


<form action="kd.php" method="post">
<label>Weight:
          <input name="weight">
          <select name="weight" id="weight">
               <option selected="selected" value="">--- select one ---</option>
               <option name="kg">kg</option>
               <option name="pounds">pounds</option>        
          </select>
</label>
<p>&nbsp;</p>      
<label>Height:
          <input name="height">
          <select name="height" id="height">
               <option selected="selected">--- select one ---</option>
               <option name="cm">cm</option>
               <option name="meters">meters</option>        
          </select>
</label>
<p>&nbsp;</p>   
<label>Calculate:
          <input name="calculate" type="submit" value="calculate">
</label>
<p>&nbsp;</p>         
BMI:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input readonly="true" name="bmi" value="<?php echo $bmi ?>">
</form>

<br/>





<body>


</body>
</body>

<p>&nbsp;<p>
<p>&nbsp;<p>
```

but it doesn't seem to be working :( Please help friends. 
Thanks :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your input/select names are the same - `<input name="weight"><select name="weight" id="weight">`/`<input name="height"><select name="height" id="height">`, so your select value will overwrite your input value.